Server active Antivirus for a SPECIFIC directory only
So I have this specific constraint in a project where we need an Antivirus to run in the background constantly, but that would only check the content of a particular directory.
We have been using ClamAV to scan specific files in the past, but I'm not quite sure if the daemon extension can be used for this specific case.
So, is there a way to do it with ClamAV?

From this stack exchange post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav
You can scan a specific file and repertory for that you need to create the file with the following command: clamscan -r -i --bell --file-list=/home/nav/ClamScanTheseFolders.txt
Once it's done add the path to the file or repertory you want to check.
Has music2myear say in the comment, ClamAV is no longer maintained, you have to be extra carefull or find another solution
Hope that help

Just a suggestion: when copying in links, remove everything including and following the "#:". What follows this is not part of the actual URL and is not supported in every browser.

And you should be aware ClamAV is no longer maintained.

Didn't see that indeed it is no longer maintained I edit my answer
